# SQL INSERT Statement causes wrong character conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

Im using LINQPad4 to commit an SQL Statement directly to my database

The statement is like:

```
INSERT INTO [mytabe] ([text]) VALUES ('срПнысчПескП'); // russian
```

The statement works but as the result I receive something like `"????????????"`

The database collation ist `SQL_Latin_General_CP1_CI_AS`

There is also an other table in my database where the russian signs are already at.

When I copy the dataset of the table (where the russian signs exist) into the table where I want to place my insert statement everything works fine.

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the datatype of `text`? If `nvarchar` then you just need the `N` prefix. `INSERT INTO [mytabe] ([text]) VALUES (N'срПнысчПескП');`

Comment: Don't use varchar fields, prefix any unicode text with N (eg N'somevalue') and replace raw SQL statements with parameterized queries. You are trying to pass an ASCII value in a Russian codepage as a plain ASCII value to the database. There is no mapping between the two codepages so the invalid characters are replaced with '?'

Comment: The datatype is nvarchar. The N-prefix seems to work. You saved my day. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any lecture where I can read about the N-prefix?

Comment: @user3049682 - There isn't much to say about it. With the prefix string literals are treated as unicode. Without it they are treated as `varchar` so any characters not representable in the code page of your database's default collation will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [mytabe] ([text]) VALUES (N'срПнысчПескП'); // russian
```

Use Nvarchar Data type.